# Cursor in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

Is there way to take in the cursor values used on a Waveform graph in LabVIEW and use those values as separate variables, without entering them in manually? Basically I have the cursor option on my front panel and the user clicks on three points, and I want the program to take those three points and find the average of them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Use the Cursor Properties:
[image: Cursor Cursor Position property]
However using the cursor means your user will have to drag the cursor. It's probably better to use mouse down and a coords-to-xy method:
[image: Curser Release vs. Mouse Down]
The upper event will be based on Cursor control by the user, the lower event will be based on click on the graph, another (perhaps better) option is mouse up. For the nitty gritty details look at the help for these events.